# ¿Como guardar registros en la base de datos que llegan como un array de objetos en el $request Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Hola a todos de ante mano gracias por sus respuestas y comentarios estoy intentando guardar registros en mi base de datos que llegan desde un formulario, el problema que me enfrento es que estos registros llegan en formato de array de objetos comparto el código de igual manera la forma en la que recibo los datos en mi función voy a compartir una pequeña parte del código para ser más claro y no abrumar con tanto código.
El dato que me interesa del $request es "customCatalog", si hacemos un return de **$request->customCatalog** me retorna lo siguiente:

```
[
  {table: 'table 1', value: 'value 1'},
  {table: 'table 2', value: 'value 2'}
]
```

En mi controlador estoy intentando lo siguiente:

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
    
              if(isset($request->customCatalog)) {
                   foreach($request->customCatalog['table'] as $table) {
                       foreach($request->customCatalog['item'] as $value) {
                          $catalog = new EmployeeHasCustomCatalog();
                          $catalog->table = $table;
                          $catalog->value = $value;
                          $catalog->save();
                       }
                    }
                }
    }
```

Creo que el problema es que no se acceder a los valores que me retorna **$request->customCatalog** para hacer uso de ello y guardar los registros en mi base de datos, gracias a todos nuevamente cualquier tipo de ayuda me serviría mucho.

Comment: ¿Recibes una cadena con formato JSON? Hay que interpretarla primero con [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Así es es una cadena en formato Json. Gracias revisaré lo que me envías.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola por si alguien más se encuentra en la misma situación de esta manera solucione mi problema, el código quedo dela siguiente manera:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) {
       $data = $request->all();
       if(isset($request->customCatalog)) {
                foreach($data['customCatalog'] as $item) {
                    
                    $table = CatAdministrator::select('id')->where('table_name', $item['table'])->first();
                
                    $catalog = new EmployeeHasCustomCatalog();
                
                    $catalog->employee_id = $employee->id;
                    $catalog->cat_custom_catalog_id = $table->id;
                    $catalog->value = $item['item'];
                    $catalog->save();
                }
            }
}
```

Guarde todo lo que trae $request en una variable $data y con eso recorrí en un ciclo foreach accediendo de esta manera: **$data['customCatalog']** ahora cada item del ciclo contendra el valor de cada una de tus propiedades puedes acceder a ellas de esta manera **item['TuValor']** Espero a ver poderme explicado, gracias a todos los que intentaron aportar algo a mi problema.

Answer (score 0):

Teniendo esa cadena, al utilizar [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php) y proporcionar el segundo parámetro como verdadero, vas a obtener un arreglo como este:

```
[
    0 => ['table' => 'table 1', 'value' => 'value 1'],
    1 => ['table' => 'table 2', 'value' => 'value 2']
]
```

Puedes recorrerlo fácilmente con un solo ciclo:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) {
    if(isset($request->customCatalog)) {
        // Decodificar JSON en un arreglo asociativo
        $arr = json_decode($request->customCatalog, true);
        // Recorrer, no se requiere índice porque es numérico
        foreach($arr as $item) {
            $catalog = new EmployeeHasCustomCatalog();
            // Acceder a cada elemento por su clave
            $catalog->table = $item['table'];
            $catalog->value = $item['value'];
            $catalog->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Triby he probado el código que me propones y me devolvio un error con el mensaje siguiente "json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"

Comment: @DarinelCigarroa, agrega una línea `dd($request->customCatalog);` antes el decodificar y agrega la salida en tu pregunta.